# Convert String into Array in Javascript Angular 6

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, multidimensional-array

I have a dynamically generated Array that is shown from `console.log(temp)`:

```
[{user_id: "test@random.com", status: "Idle"}], 
[{user_id: "whatever@random.com", status: "Busy"}]
```

My code:

```
this.scheduleService.getShiftSchedule().subscribe((temp)=>{
  this.api = temp;
  console.log(temp);
})
```

How do I change the format of my Array to become like the Array below?

```
[[{id: 1,content: 'test@random.com'},{id: 2,content: 'Idle'}],
[{id: 1,content: 'whatever@random.com'},{id: 2,content: 'Busy'}]]
```

Comment: So you have two dimension array as input. And the each array can have multiple  records?

Comment: `console.log(temp)` is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the objects by taking an array of the wanted keys and their `id`.

```js
var data = [{ user_id: "test@random.com", status: "Idle" }, { user_id: "whatever@random.com", status: "Busy" }],
    ids = [['user_id', 1], ['status', 2]],
    result = data.map(o => ids.map(([key, id]) => ({ id, content: o[key] })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The given error "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'." man @Nina Scholz

Comment: It works, i forget to add some Map library. Thanks @Nina Scholz

Answer (score 0):

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

```
var newArr = [];
while(arr.length) newArr.push(arr.splice(0,3));

console.log(newArr)
```

you may try like this

Answer (score 0):

var array = JSON.parse("[" + string + "]");

Comment: Read the question before answering

Comment: Not an answer !